# Fluctuations of free energy in quantum statistical mechanics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, quantum-statistics, fluctuation-dissipation

I want to calculate the fluctuation of the mean value of the free energy, $\langle F \rangle$, which I denote as $(\Delta F)^2 = \langle F^2\rangle - \langle F\rangle^2$. Since I have calculated the canonical partition function, $Z$, I can easily compute $\langle F \rangle = -\frac 1 \beta \ln Z$.

But how to calculate $(\Delta F)^2$ ?

Using the definition $F=E-TS$ and $(\Delta F)^2 = \langle F^2\rangle - \langle F\rangle^2$, I found the following expression

$$
(\Delta F)^2 = (\Delta E)^2 + T^2 (\Delta S)^2 - 2T\big [ \langle E S \rangle - \langle E \rangle \langle S \rangle \big ]
$$
where $(\Delta E)^2 = k_B T^2 C_V $ and $(\Delta S)^2 = k_B C_V$ are the fluctuations of the inner energy and entropy respectively. The only problem is the term $\langle E S \rangle$.

In analogy to $\langle S \rangle = -k_B \text{Tr}[\rho\ln\rho]$ I write
$$
\langle E S \rangle = -k_B \text{Tr}[\rho H \ln \rho]
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $\rho$ the density matrix. But is this correct? Since there is no such thing as an entropy operator, I feel unsure about this naiv approach...

Comment: Free energy is not the average of some microscopic quantity. $F = -\frac{1}{\beta}\ln Z$ not $\langle F\rangle$. It is a property of the distribution of micro-states (and there energies), rather than of a single micro-state. Consequently I don't think it makes sense to talk about it having fluctuations.

Comment: Oh... that's true... I just realized that as I found that $(\Delta F)^2 = 0$ from my formulas above. Awkward...

Comment: I think we can delete the entire thread here

Comment: @thyme  But I found it interesting and so might others? Incidentally I came at it by going back to $Z=\sum_{i} e^{-\beta E_i}$ and realising that the $E_i$ were fixed for the system (at constant volume). But By Symmetry has explained it more neatly.

Comment: If the OP wants to close or delete the question that's fine, but please don't leave it open you already have an answer or consider it not an issue.  The OP can even post an answer themselves - it's been done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will repeat what I said in the comments as an answer.

Free energy is not the average of some microscopic quantity. It is a property of the distribution of micro-states (and there energies), rather than of a single micro-state. Consequently I don't think it makes sense to talk about it having fluctuations.

Another way to view this, as pointed out by @PhilipWood, is to look at the partition function and see that 
$$
Z = \sum_i e^{-\beta E_i}
$$
depends only on the macroscopic properties (volume, temperature, etc.) of the system and not on the particular micro-state you are in. Consequently the same applies to 
$$
F = -\frac{1}{\beta}\ln Z
$$

Comment: I think $F$, if defined just using this equation, certainly will not fluctuate, but I think the thermodynamic free energy $F$ defined by $F=U-TS$ does indeed fluctuate and this formula is only true in the ensemble average, i.e. $F$ here should really be $\langle F \rangle$

Comment: You could define fluctuations in the free energy that way but I have never encountered anyone doing that. It implies a notion of "instantaneous free energy" which I am not aware of having any particular physical meaning. Furthermore, depending on how $T$ and $S$ are defined it may be that neither of these quantities fluctuate either, in which case your fluctuations in $F$ are identical to your fluctuations in $U$.